# How to rollback a database to specific date in liquibase

Tags: liquibase

I am trying to rollback a database based on specific date.

> liquibase rollbackToDate 2013-05-14 10:13:16

it throws following error:

```
Error:Unexpected date/time format.
```

Please share the exact command for this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Liquibase looks for the date in the format:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
```

So try:

```
2013-05-14T10:13:16
```

Comment: I am facing [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.liquibase:liquibase-maven-plugin:3.0.5:rollback (default-cli) on project liquibase: Error setting up or running Liquibase: Error parsing rollbackDate: Unparseable date: "2016-12-09T11:49:00"
[ERROR] Date must match pattern: MMM d, yyyy
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]

Answer (score 0):

When I tried to rollback by date using liquibase,got error date format error.
I had to give the date format in **"DD-MMM-YYYY" format (example: 25-OCT-2019)**.This fixed issue for me.

However,I think liquibase doesnot provide rollback to specific time. Only date is supported.